# AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'StandardScaler'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn KNN ( K- nearest neighbour ) algorithm and while normalizing data I got the error mentioned in the title.

**SK-learn Version :0.24.2**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv(r'Data_files/TeleCust.csv')
df.head()

df.columns

X = df[['region', 'tenure','age', 'marital', 'address', 'income', 'ed', 'employ','retire', 'gender', 'reside']]
X[0:5]

y = df['custcat'].values
y[0:5]


X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
X[0:5]
```

**Output:**

```
X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'StandardScaler'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in your import:
Use this instead:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
```

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv(r'Data_files/TeleCust.csv')
df.head()

# print(df['custcat'].value_counts())

# df.hist(column= 'income', bins= 50)
# plt.show()

df.columns

X = df[['region', 'tenure','age', 'marital', 'address', 'income', 'ed', 'employ','retire', 'gender', 'reside']]
X[0:5]

y = df['custcat'].values
y[0:5]


X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
X[0:5]
```

Comment: That was a silly mistake I made, Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your import, try:

```py
import sklearn.preprocessing
...
X = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
```

`StandardScaler` is found in the `preprocessing` module, whereas you just imported the `sklearn` module and called it `preprocessing` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better in my opinion:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
[...]
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))
```